# Accumulator is failing to update on pyspark job ran on dataproc cluster

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, mlflow, dataproc

So the individual pyspark jobs do complete I can see that in the logs but while accumulation I get the following exception. The same piece of code when executed locally is working fine.
The cluster shows task completed successfully but I get accumulator error.

Logs for successful working of individual threads.

```
23/06/11 15:03:35 INFO LoggerProvider: deleted one hot encode
23/06/11 15:03:35 INFO LoggerProvider: Started Assemble Vector
23/06/11 15:03:36 INFO LoggerProvider: Completed Assemble Vector
23/06/11 15:03:36 INFO LoggerProvider: started training pipeline
23/06/11 15:03:36 INFO LoggerProvider: Started mlflow active run
```

Exception log

```
23/06/11 14:02:53 ERROR DAGScheduler: Failed to update accumulator 0 (org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2) for task 54
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:200) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2.merge(PythonRDD.scala:734) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$updateAccumulators$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1610) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$updateAccumulators$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1601) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62) ~[scala-library-2.12.14.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55) ~[scala-library-2.12.14.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49) ~[scala-library-2.12.14.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.updateAccumulators(DAGScheduler.scala:1601) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1749) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2858) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2803) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2792) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
23/06/11 14:02:53 ERROR DAGScheduler: Failed to update accumulator 0 (org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2) for task 57
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2.merge(PythonRDD.scala:732) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$updateAccumulators$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1610) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$updateAccumulators$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1601) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62) ~[scala-library-2.12.14.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55) ~[scala-library-2.12.14.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49) ~[scala-library-2.12.14.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.updateAccumulators(DAGScheduler.scala:1601) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1749) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2858) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2803) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2792) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
```

Following is the code for my spark initialization

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn')\
    .appName("pyspark-test")\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mlflow:mlflow-spark:1.30.0,io.findify:s3mock_2.12:0.1.8,org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.13:3.4.0,org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.1")\
    .config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "36000")\
    .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")\
    .getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', bucket)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")
```

Following is the code

```
    logger.info("started training pipeline")
    mlflow.pyspark.ml.autolog()
    train, test = df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3], seed = 2018)
    with mlflow.start_run() as active_run:
        logger.info("Started mlflow active run")

        rfc = RandomForestClassifier(featuresCol="features", labelCol="label")
        rfc = rfc.fit(train)
        signature = infer_signature( df.select("features"), df.select("label"))
        mlflow.spark.log_model(
                spark_model=rfc, 
                artifact_path=f"rfc-model",
                registered_model_name=f"rfc-model",
                signature=signature
            )
        evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
        labelCol="product_id_in", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy")
        accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(rfc.transform(test))
        mlflow.log_metric("recall", accuracy)
        logger.info("Completed active run")
    mlflow.end_run()
    logger.info("completed training pipeline")
```